# rufus-scheduler gem not working in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, scheduled-tasks, state-machine, rufus-scheduler

I am using the state_machine gem and the rufus-scheduler gem.  State machine is working perfectly.  Rufus-scheduler, however, is not.  I am building this program just to get used to rufus gem.  10 seconds after :accepted is transitioned to :both, it should then transition to :only_employer.  However, rufus-scheduler for some reason is not working.  The transition to :both works, but then it does not transition to :only_employer.  How do I fix this?  Thanks.

```
class Schedule < ActiveRecord::Base
    require 'rufus-scheduler'
    scheduler = Rufus::Scheduler.new

    def set_schedule
        scheduler.in '10' do #documentation says this should be 10 seconds
          self.change_to_done
        end
    end

    state_machine :accepted, :initial => :none do
         after_transition :any => :both, :do => :set_schedule
         event :change_to_done do
             transition :both => :only_employer 
         end
    end

end
```

Comment: Add scheduler.join as last statement in your set_schedule method. BTW I think you should not use rufus-scheduler in this way

Comment: Thanks, added it but it did not work.  I looked at the documentation but can't quite figure out what 'scheduler.join' is supposed to do.  Would you mind explaining it?

Comment: 'scheduler.join' makes the current thread join the scheduler thread. It's not what you want. 'scheduler.join' is used in standalone scripts, not in code ran via Rails or Sinatra.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using rufus-scheduler for this is overkill.

```
def set_schedule
  Thread.new do
    sleep 10
    self.change_to_done
  end
end
```

should be sufficient.

But then is the "server" you run Rails on top of thread-friendly? If not, you'd better pass the task to something like resque or sidekick.

Comment: Thanks, but like I said, this is really just something I'm trying to do to learn rufus before i put it into something more complex.  I also tried rescue, and found it way too complicated.  I also couldn't figure out how to make rescue do jobs in a fixed amount of time.  i could only figure out how to get it to repeat jobs in the background, not to a job after a given event.

Comment: Reading this might help you get help: http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/bugs.html

You're giving no details about your setting (Ruby, Rails, rufus-scheduler versions, ...). You're not telling what you're running Rails on top of (Thin, Passenger, Unicorn, ... ?)

Resque-scheduler could interest you. https://github.com/resque/resque-scheduler

Comment: I am not running rails on top of anything and I spent several hours with rescue.  I am using the most up to date version of rufus (I can't see what version it is on github.  It is whatever version you get from putting gem 'rufus-scheduler' in the gem file.  I am very new to background jobs so there is a good chance there is some basic knowledge I'm missing, but I've gone through several rails cast and searched the internet for a while but can't find anything.

Comment: So you're probably running Rails on top of Webrick (Rails tells you when you start it). It's "resque" not "rescue". Try the thread version above to see if the transition happens or not, that thread version is almost a mini rufus-scheduler, observe what happens and report it precisely. You'd better learn how to request help else you'll go on wasting time for many people including yourself.

Comment: Great, thank you.  I can make this a new question if you'd like, but I'm trying to figure out: does " scheduler.in '10d' " wait exactly 10 days (exactly 240 hours) or does it wait until midnight of the 10th day or does it make some other type of estimate?

Comment: It waits until 240 hours have elapsed.